# Is LINQ resetting the database field type?

Tags: sql-server, linq, orm

We have a table with many NVARCHAR(255) fields which are forcing a possible truncation exception "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminate.".

To avoid this, I just need to increase the field type to NVARCHAR(MAX). But once LINQ runs on the database, it resets the field type back to NVARCHAR(255).

If I run a normal query in Management Studio, the field type is kept the same with no problems.

Needless to say, I don't have the source code of the binary wasting my day. Otherwise, I would just update the context class.

Is there any possible turn-around for me to keep the field types?

Comment: LINQ to SQL? LINQ to Entities?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on orm, there may be a setting which force to update db schema according to domain model in your code base (like CodeFirst of EntityFramework or simillar thing in NHibernate).
So it's better to look at source code of your app, and orm setting in specifically.